# mdi form-->> child form 1(button-->> child form2) c # child form from button of some other child form

Tags: c#, .net, oop, mdi, mdichild

i have mdi form "m1" in which OnLoad open child form "ch1" in child form i have one button "b1" which further open new form "ch2" but that form should be the child of "md1" ch2.MdiParent = this; is not working form me

Comment: Please explain just what is not working, show some code, give us a chance to help; what you have written is at least as enigmatic for us as for you..

Comment: i got the ans by the way thanks for your concern and the ans is
//ch2.MdiParent=this;
ch2.MdiParent=this.mdiParent;
thanks alot man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Child Form 2 is being created by Child Form 1, it needs to reference the MdiParent of Child Form 1, not `this` (which is not an MDI form):

```
ch2.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
```

Comment: actualy i was wondering how can i pull back child form for example if ch2.Hide(); will hide the form can i reopen that form from some other form ..?

Comment: @AbhinavAggarwal If you have a reference to it you can.

Comment: Student_Registration sr = null;

Comment: private bool CheckOpened(string name)
        {
            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

            foreach (Form frm in fc)
            {
                if (frm.Text == name)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

Comment: private void aDDSTUDENTToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sr == null || sr.Text == "")
            {
                sr = new Student_Registration();
                sr.MdiParent = this;
                sr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                sr.Show();
            }
            else if (CheckOpened(sr.Text))
            {
                sr.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                sr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                sr.Show();
                sr.Focus();
            }
        }

Comment: but when i use this 
id hide minimized forms on status bar this is my problm how to solve this